# Is reusing sources self-plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, self-plagiarism

I have a class that I have to research a topic on. It can be anything and all I have to do is inform the class about the topic. It's not super intense research, just a small amount, enough for a 5 minute presentation.

However, before, I had a research project that took up almost a whole school year about a topic we chose. It's a topic I'm interested in and I was wondering if it counts as self-plagiarism if I reuse sources from the old research project? Not all of them just a handful. It's almost all just facts and not much of my own analysis so would it be counted as plagiarism?

Does turnitin count it as plagiarism if they find 2 papers using the same sources? The thing I'm concerned about is we have to do an annotated bib and I took the sources from an old annotated bib. However the info paragraph I basically rewrote it all and its a lot more simple than my old one, which has a lot of specifics. Also all the sources I am using are on my old annotated bib.

Comment: You should ask this your teacher.

Comment: Plagiarism while doing assignments is really too much of a concept

Comment: @yuq If all of the sources also appear in the previous project and both have been submitted to Turnitin, yes they will be flagged.

Comment: As a side note: If you are choosing classes where the homework is capable of being copy-pasted, then you have other problems. You should be picking classes that don't overlap so closely, and that advance you more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will be flagged by Turnitin. However, why don't you just cite your own research? In that case, it's not plagiarism because you cite your own work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Self plagiarism is when you use your old work without citing it. It can be avoided with citation, just as you would if the original was from another author. So, in this case, it would probably be considered to be self plagiarism.

However, you have another problem in that the professor may have wanted you to do something new, not to recycle work from the past. In that case, you could wind up in trouble even if you use proper citation of the older work. That would avoid self-plagiarism, but might not avoid sanction from the professor.

Ask the professor if it is appropriate for you to draw on old work for this. We can't answer for them, but do this before you make assumptions and end up in trouble.